Relativistic kinetic energy in non-inertial frames
This is probably a really silly question, however, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around kinetic energy in SR. For inertial frames of reference, I have absolutely 0 problem in interpreting why $K = (\gamma-1)mc^2$ holds true for inertial frames. Does this equation hold true for non-inertial frames as well? I couldn't be quite sure as no source I've found explores this (maybe there is nothing to be explore and I'm overcomplicating) topic. Also, doesn't the speed of light change in non-inertial frames? E.g. when coordinate transformations $$x = (\frac{c^2}{\alpha}+\xi)\sinh\frac{\alpha\tau}{c}$$
$$t = (\frac{c}{\alpha}+\frac{\xi}{c})\sinh\frac{\alpha\tau}{c}$$ are given, $\frac{d\xi}{d\tau}$ becomes $\left(1+\frac{\alpha\tau}{c^2}\right)c$ for $ds^2 = 0$, which indicates the speed of light in the given frame if I'm not mistaken. Wouldn't this change the expression for kinetic energy as well? If it doesn't why?
